# Filter revision history

Tags: discussion, feature-request, revisions-list, tag-filters

I like using [filters](https://stackexchange.com/filters) to find questions to answer.

However, do filters track revisions like questions and answers on Stack Exchange? I would sometimes like to look at older versions of a filter.

Comment: They don't track changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, at least not publicly. If you want this feature, retag to a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)!